# Script to empty and/or delete jms queues from Websphere Process Server

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, websphere-6.1

suppose I have the following JMS queues

- "doc/queue1"
- "home/queue2"
- "someOtherQueue"

added in a websphere process server, how can I write a script to clear and/or delete them? looking around the web I haven't found a solution to my problem yet unfortunately, what i found though is that it's probably gonna be a JYthon script which i wouldn't know how to write

thanks in advance for the help guys

Answer (score 1):

I have written a script that already does most of what you need in the article *[Mission:Messaging: Easing administration and debugging with circular queues](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1103_mismes/1103_mismes.html)*.  The script uses the Q program from [SupportPac MA01](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMA01) to clear messages.  You could use the client version of the Q program to do the same thing remotely. Although I've written my script in Perl I have seen versions of it in Korn Shell and Windows Batch as well.